# JSON mapping exception

Tags: java, json, spring

Estoy empleando las funcionalidades de la librería Jackson para realizar conversiones de objetos a string. La cual convierte un objeto a un JSON. Es enviado vía rest a un servidor. Pero el servidor me devuelve el siguiente mensaje de excepción:

> nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x65

Y el objeto que envió es un JSON bien formateado ya que lo he validado previamente con una [herramienta](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). También he de decir que poniendo puntos de parada en el server, el programa me salta la excepción antes de entrar al controlador, así que imagino que ese check lo realiza una de la dependencias inyectadas en string.

¿Como podría saber que carácter es el 0x65 para poder visualizar el carácter del string?
¿Y alguna idea de que puede estar ocurriendo?

Un saludo

Está definido de la siguiente manera:

```
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap();
headers.put("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponseBean httpResponseBean = this.httpUtils.postRequest(uri, headers, this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(trx));
```

**EDIT**
He dado con la solucion aunque no se como solventarla. El problema se da cuando añado caracteres como la ñ o letras con tildes. Como podria habilitar la capacidad de entender esos caracteres?

Comment: El problema parece ser que declaras que vas a mandar algo usando la codificación UTF-8 pero acabas mandando un texto en formato JSON con otra codificación distinta. Deberías poner el código de cómo generas el JSON

Comment: En teoria al crear un objeto ObjectMapper establce por defecto el encoding a UTF-8

Comment: No, ObjectMapper crea un *String*. El String es transformado a un array de bytes al enviarlo por el método `postRequest`. Un String no tiene *codificación*, del mismo modo que un Float no tiene *formato* intrínseco

Comment: Comprueba que formato espera recibir el servidor. SI puedes o necesita cambia la configuración del servidor para que acepte el formato UTF-8. Otra opción no utilices Ñ o tildes.